# Я не могу понять где здесь ошибка? у меня выводит это Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: server-side-rendering

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";
import { AlertContext } from "../context/alert/alertContext";



export const Form = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const alert = useContext(AlertContext)

    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        alert.show(value, "success")
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Введите названия заметки"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```